# Implementing custom Push Service In Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Google most "mouth praised" GCM to an extent but got heart broken after a deep research about GCM and found out its not very reliable for PUSH which i already experienced myself after some experiments(Issues with google high heartbeat rate/closed tcp connections ..etc) it delivers messages most time very slow after a wait time of lets say 15 minutes.

So what then is the best approach to have a push notification service that best suits a chat application.

1) Do i keep requesting data from my Node js server for every particular X-interval via a service.

2) Or is there a better library. (just that i'm very skeptical about using external libraries)
I know Facebook uses MQTT but the documentation is pretty full of Chinese language.

This might be an awkward question but i have had sleepless night on this and its pissing me off.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you don't use notifications only if you want to make a chat application, because notifications not allways are delivered correctly.

Search about "Long polling" in Google, it's interesting to simulate a TCP under the 80 port and it's very simple to understand.

Comment: its a chat application like said.